# Group Firebase FCM on Android Device

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am trying to send cloud messages using the Firebase console. I am doing this for android device.

The push notifications do appear on the device fine along with the data sent with it.

But each notification shows up on its own. Meaning if I send 3 notifications three items show up in the notification bar.

What  I want to achieve is that all the notifications to be grouped under one heading. As you have in WhatsApp or Facebook.

How can this be achieved using the Firebase Console?

Answer (score 1):

By *grouping* the notification, do you mean *stacking* or [bundling notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#bundle)?

If so, this is actually depends on how you handle notifications in your client app. You simply have to make use of the [setGroup()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroup(java.lang.String)) to add all your notifications to a single group then calling [notify()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html#notify(int,android.app.Notification)) to let the NotificationManager of the changes.

This [Add Each Notification to a Group](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html#AddGroup) documentation pretty much sums it all up.