# Android FCM notification bundle issue(Queued notifications)

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

How to see queued notifications on notification pannel? I meant how to bundle notification, Already I have seen android developers page but didn't get any solution.
*Please refer following image...*
 [image]

Comment: Is your device running on Android Nougat (7.0)? According to my understanding, bundled notification is only available from 7.0 and above.

Comment: No, currently I'm using api 21 and I want to get budled notification (Iwhatever called for given figure?? confused??) as well as it should be support for all api levels??

Comment: CodePlay, I get notification... it's fine but my problem is when I send another notification ,it overwrites on preveious one.. I'm stucked??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group Firebase FCM on Android Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394210/group-firebase-fcm-on-android-device)

Comment: I found out by myself here is the solution

Comment: NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION, notification);
        ID_NOTIFICATION = ID_NOTIFICATION+1;

Answer (score 0):

Put different id for each notification like this:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); notificationManager.notify(Sys, notification);
```